# Post request in cURL with Box API only

Tags: curl, box

I created a box application with XXXX name. I have client_id: XXXX and client_secret: XXXX . For post method i am using below url:

`curl https://app.box.com/api/oauth2/token \ -d 'grant_type=authorization_code&code={your_code}&client_id={your_client_id}&client_secret={your_client_secret}' \ -X POST`

My doubt is how to use curl in browser. I am getting error by giving above url as

`https://app.box.com/api/oauth2/token \ d'grant_type=authorization_code&code=XXXX&client_id=XXXX&client_secret=XXXX' \ -X POST`

Give an example with Box api only by  using client-id and client-secret. How to use post method with cURL.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .Net version 4.0 or higher then you can use the Request Response type also called POSTMAN method.

It can be used like this:

**Requesting the API:

```
            WebRequest request2 = WebRequest.Create("https://app.box.com/api/oauth2/token");
            request2.Method = "POST";
            string postData2 = "grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=" + YourRefreshToken + "&client_id=" + YourClientId + "&client_secret=" + YourClientSecret;
            byte[] byteArray2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData2);
            request2.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request2.ContentLength = byteArray2.Length;
            Stream dataStream2 = request2.GetRequestStream();
            dataStream2.Write(byteArray2, 0, byteArray2.Length);
            dataStream2.Close();
```

**Fetching the response from API:

```
            WebResponse response2 = request2.GetResponse();
            string response12 = (((HttpWebResponse)response2).StatusDescription);
            dataStream2 = response2.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader2 = new StreamReader(dataStream2);
            string responseFromServer2 = reader2.ReadToEnd();
```

This will return you the AccessToken required for accessing the contents in the Box Account.